# Oracle: How do I query a Hierarchical table?

Tags: oracle, query, view, hierarchy

## Background

This is for the construction of some views we'll be using for reporting.

I have an table of locations, the **key fields being "location" and "parent"**.

The structure that these two fields create, level-wise, are along the lines of Company Name --> Campus Name --> Building Name --> Floor Name --> Room Name. Company name remains the same and Campus name remains the same in this case.

The structure of locations generally looks like this:

```
                                 +-----------+
                                 | Org. Name |
                                 +-----+-----+
                                       |
                                 +-----v-----+
           +--------------------+|Campus Name|+---+--+-------------+
           |                     +--+--------+    |                |
           |                        |             |                |
           |                        |             |                |
        +--+-----+           +------+-+        +--+----+       +---+---+
    +--+| BLDG-01|+--+       | BLDG-02|        |BLDG-03|       |Grounds|
    |   +--------+   |       +--------+        +-------+       +-------+
  +-+------+   +-----+--+
  |Floor-01|   |Basement+-------+
  +-+------+   +--------+       |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    | +----------+      +-------+--+
    +-+Room 1-001|      |Room B-002|
      +----------+      +----------+
```

Every location links back to its parent location, which is ultimately the organization name. Currently, there is only one organization and one campus.

## Goals

- **I would like to be able to query all locations beneath any given location at the "Building" level.** This is so I can return things like how many workorders have been performed for any location within a given building.
- **I would like to be able to determine which sub-location belongs to which building**. Essentially the reverse; I would like to go from any level beneath the building level and trace back up to what the building is.
- **I would like this to be in a view**. That means, I would like to have a table that for every item at the "building" level, lists the building in the left-hand column and all possible locations UNDER that building in the right-hand column. This way I'd have a list that I could query at any time to find which locations are part of which building.

## Attempts and Doing it Right

I've attempted to do this through horribly constructed views, UNION queries, etc. -- which all have seemed like a bad idea. I know Oracle possesses a mechanism for this through "CONNECT BY"; I'm just not sure how to make use of it.

Comment: How are "root" nodes identified? Is parent `NULL` for them? How do you identify a "building level"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name logically, I suppose the "building" level would be anything with a parent that is the campus name, i.e. anything with a parent of "MAINCAMPUS". The root of all the nodes is "COMPANYNAME", which is the parent of "MAINCAMPUS", and all buildings (plus "grounds") have MAINCAMPUS as a parent.

Comment: wow! how did you create that!!
Google for "Adjacency Model in SQL" you will be all set

Comment: PS, for those who were interested in how I made the diagram, I used a nifty little web site called http://asciiflow.com/ -- I'm a big fan for situations like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FrusteratedWithFormsDesigner has the right direction(+1).  Here is what I think you are looking for specifically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BuildingSubs AS
   SELECT connect_by_root location "Building", location "SubLocation"
   FROM some_table l
   START WITH l.Location IN 
      (
         SELECT location FROM
         (
         SELECT level MyLevel, location FROM some_table 
         START WITH parent IS NULL 
         CONNECT BY PRIOR location=parent
         )
         WHERE MyLevel=3   
      )
   CONNECT BY PRIOR l.location = l.parent;

select * from BuildingSubs; 

Building             SubLocation        
-------------------- --------------------
BLDG-01              BLDG-01              
BLDG-01              Basement             
BLDG-01              Room B-002           
BLDG-01              Floor-01             
BLDG-01              Room 1-001           
BLDG-02              BLDG-02              
BLDG-03              BLDG-03              
Grounds              Grounds
```

The view accomplishes all three goals.  You can query it for a building to find everything it contains and you can query it for a sub-location to find what building it is in.

```
drop table some_table;
create table some_table (Location Varchar2(20), Parent Varchar2(20));

insert into some_table values ('Org. Name',NULL);
insert into some_table values ('MAINCAMPUS','Org. Name');
insert into some_table values ('BLDG-01','MAINCAMPUS');
insert into some_table values ('BLDG-02','MAINCAMPUS');
insert into some_table values ('BLDG-03','MAINCAMPUS');
insert into some_table values ('Grounds','MAINCAMPUS');
insert into some_table values ('Floor-01','BLDG-01');
insert into some_table values ('Basement','BLDG-01');
insert into some_table values ('Room B-002','Basement');
insert into some_table values ('Room 1-001','Floor-01');
```

If you don't want to count the building itself as one of the sub-locations you can wrap the existing query in one the eliminates entries in which the building and sublocation are the same.

Comment: Leigh, this was exactly it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

`CONNECT BY` is the correct way to handle data that is naturally recursive.

I don't know what your table looks like but maybe something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table st
START WITH st.location = 'BLDG-01'
CONNECT BY PRIOR st.location = st.parent;
```

This should get nodes under "BLDG-01".

The `START WITH` clause is your base case.

Another explanation (aside from the Oracle one which I assume you've already read and had trouble with, it's probably very terse):

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

Also:

http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html

And:

http://www.oradev.com/connect_by.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting it enough to realize that I don't think I phrased my question well. My table structure has two columns -- "location" and "parent". The hierarchy these create is defined by my ascii chart. I would like to construct a view that shows, for each location at the "building" level, all locations underneath its branch. My goal is to be able to query a building and get all its sub-locations, or query a sublocation and see which building it belongs to, through a view (so no hard-defined "building-x" in the query). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but maybe something like this:

```
select location, 
       parent,
       sys_connect_by_path(location, '/') as item_list,
       case level
         when 1 then 'building'
         when 2 then 'floor'
         when 3 then 'room'
       end as item_type
from some_table 
start with parent = 'MAINCAMPUS'
connect by prior location = parent;
```

This will show you the hierarchy for each location